# How can I test, inside EL, if a JSF composite component is used with an f:ajax tag?

Tags: ajax, jsf, composite-component

My composite component has optional support for f:ajax tags using a clientBehavior tag:

**singleMultiSelect.xhtml**

```
<cc:interface componentType="singleMultiSelect">

        <!-- The initial list of objects -->
        <cc:attribute name="list" type="java.util.List" required="true"/>
        <!-- The selected objects -->
        <cc:attribute name="selected" type="java.util.Collection" required="true"/>
        <!-- whether to display the selectOneMenu (true) or selectManyBox (false) -->
        <cc:attribute name="singleSelect" type="java.lang.Boolean" 
                  required="false" default="true"/>  
        <cc:clientBehavior name="valueChange" event="valueChange"
                       targets="selectOneMenu selectManyListbox"/>

    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>

        <span id="#{cc.clientId}">

            <ace:checkboxButton id="singleSelectChkBx"
                                value="#{cc.attrs.singleSelect}">
                <ace:ajax render="#{cc.clientId}"/>
            </ace:checkboxButton>                    

            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu" 
                             rendered="#{cc.attrs.singleSelect}"
                             binding="#{cc.singleSelected}">                    
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.list}"/>

                <!-- THIS PART IS NOT WORKING BECAUSE IT RETURNS 0
                     NO MATTER IF F:AJAX IS USED OR NOT -->
                <c:if test="#{cc.getClientBehaviors().size() > 0}">
                    <f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
                            listener="#{cc.updateSelected}"/>
                </c:if>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:selectManyListbox id="selectManyListbox" 
                                 rendered="#{! cc.attrs.singleSelect}"
                                 value="#{cc.attrs.selected}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.list}"/>
            </h:selectManyListbox>

        </span>

    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

**SingleMultiSelect.java**

```
public class SingleMultiSelect extends UINamingContainer {

    private UISelectOne singleSelected;

    public SingleMultiSelect() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void processUpdates(FacesContext context) {
        super.processUpdates(context);

        if (getAttributes().get("singleSelect") == Boolean.TRUE) {
            HashSet selected = new HashSet();
            if(singleSelected.getValue() != null) {
                selected.add(singleSelected.getValue());
            }
            getValueExpression("selected").setValue(context.getELContext(), selected);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        if (getAttributes().get("singleSelect") == Boolean.TRUE) {
            Collection selected = (Collection) getAttributes().get("selected");
            if (selected != null && !selected.isEmpty()) {
                singleSelected.setValue(selected.iterator().next());
            } else {
                singleSelected.setValue(null);
            }
        }

        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    public void updateSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (getAttributes().get("singleSelect") == Boolean.TRUE) {
            HashSet selected = new HashSet();
            if(singleSelected.getValue() != null) {
                selected.add(singleSelected.getValue());
            }
            getValueExpression("selected").setValue(context.getELContext(), selected);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the singleSelected
     */
    public UISelectOne getSingleSelected() {
        return singleSelected;
    }

    /**
     * @param singleSelected the singleSelected to set
     */
    public void setSingleSelected(UISelectOne singleSelected) {
        this.singleSelected = singleSelected;
    }
}
```

How can I test, within EL, if the client is actually using ajax.   For example:

```
<mylib:mycomp />
```

vs

```
<mylib:mycomp>
    <f:ajax event="valueChange"/>
</mylib:mycomp>
```

In the code, you can see I tried using cc.getClientBehaviors().size() to see if there is a client behavior populated, but it always returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSF component has to implement the *ClientBehaviorHolder* interface and the *getEventNames()* method needs to be overridden to return the list of supported events:

SingleMultiSelect.java:

```
public class SingleMultiSelect extends UINamingContainer implements ClientBehaviorHolder {

    ...

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getEventNames() {
        Collection<String> eventNames = new HashSet<>();
        eventNames.add("valueChange");
        return eventNames;
    }

    ...
}
```

Once that was done, @rvillar's answer worked:

1) If a particular behavior was inserted

```
#{empty cc.getClientBehaviors().get("valueChange")}
```

2) or any

```
#{cc.getClientBehaviors().size() > 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check inside your composite component code, these attributes for example.

1) If a particular behavior was inserted

```
#{empty cc.getClientBehaviors().get("valueChange")}
```

2) or any

```
#{cc.getClientBehaviors().size() > 0}
```

Comment: This does not appear to work.  cc.getClientBehaviors().get("valueChange") returns nothing.  cc.getClientBehaviors().size() returns 0.  (I put them both into h:outputText tags)

Comment: I also stepped through my main UINamingContainer component and this.getClientBehaviors().size() also returns 0.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: wsaxton, can you post a short version of your composite component code?

Comment: I put my code in there and commented where tried using your logic.

Comment: Great @wsaxton! To make your job easier override getDefaultEventName() method in your component, to return 'valueChange' as your default event. This way you won't need to specify the event name every time you insert a <f:ajax> tag.
`@Override
public String getDefaultEventName() {
 return "valueChange";
}`

Comment: Awesome, will do.  Thanks for the help!